# swift3 how to create xib for already created view controller

Tags: ios, xcode8

I have created a class and connected in storyboard and later for my requirement i have created xib for that class but i'm not able to connect my class to that xib.

Comment: Check if the `File Owner` class is your viewController class

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti Its worked Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xib name should be the same as controller class, then open XIB file-> file owners and select your controller Class.

To open your controller with xib you can use this line of code

```
let viewController = YourController(nibName: "YourController", bundle: nil)
```

Comment: XIB file-> file owners and select your controller Class. is worked for me

Comment: `Xib name should be the same as controller class` that's not needed.

Comment: yes, you right, but for better readable of code and project:)

Comment: @VadimKozak Will you please tell me how to load the nib 

  class func instanceFromNib() -> Screen1Main {
        return UINib(nibName: "Screen1Main", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! Screen1Main
    }

Its giving error

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x608000012080> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.